# Why fight against adharma if everything is already planned?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, karma, dharma

If one knows that what has to happen will happen, by the will of Supreme, then why do we protect our dharma? We do not control the results (fruits). By the will of Supreme, if dharma has to stay, it will, and if it does not have to, it will not. Then why should we try to protect our dharma when the results are not in our hands?

Comment: Technically you are right , but in contrast all the living beings are having their  some sort free will also , which is given. Also their are powers given to us for averting the pre planed situations, We also can divert what has already planed (in some extent) by doing right karma. The rule applies to living beings and not to things like "earth" or "dhrama" etc. e.g. if suppose a astriod will be colliding with earth in some time ,that is pre-written , but we also have given powers to overcome that situation by karma and our brain.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I don't think what you said is correct. What is already planned can rarely be avoided, also not by doing right karma, but by immense devotion. But that is very rare case. And nowhere in the scriptures it is written that right karma has avoided something that is already planned.

Comment: why eat food? if God's will you have to eat, the food will be put inside the mouth, isn't it! There is always a conflict between heart and mind. When both are in unison, all doubts vanish. For the one who is having the complete faith, so it shall be done! But the Mind always casts doubt. That's why Sadhana is needed. You have to attain the level of faith or Realization that everything indeed is His Will and that you really have to do nothing. It's absolutely True. But until you attain such a state of mind, sadhana helps. And one of the steps in sadhana is righteousness or being Dharmic. :)

Comment: @Sai If someone has attained that realization, how does he know his duties? He will just meet his bodily needs and pray to god in the rest of the time and do nothing else?

Comment: @user5155835 If a sadhaka has attained that realization, then there is no knowing His duty. He is always in touch with the ever loving Self, the in-dweller Lord Krishna. He will not be subject to the six enemies of the Mind. He will be free of the ups and downs of happiness + sorrow. He will be ever at peace. Most importantly, he will Love All unconditionally including Himself. Good luck

Comment: @Sai So will he just meet his bodily needs and pray to god in the rest of the time and do nothing else?

Comment: @user5155835 How come you make a difference in bodily needs. They too are subject to the Will of God isnt it. If he is attached to his bodily needs, then he has not yet attained realization. The one who has realization, will be ever in touch with His Self. Then if at all He does anything, it will be based on the will of God, who is guiding him. I think your question is 'Without the realization, how do I conduct myself?' am I right? For a man of realization, this question is meaningless because He is daily communicating with God and so He knows exactly what God wants.

Answer (score 6):

By considering the point "Everything is already planned", then literally everything is planned including our fight against Adharma. Means we cannot stop ourselves in playing our part which is planned for us.

Now coming to the scriptural basis, [Bhagvad Gita in Chapter three Karma Yoga](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3) section says that everyone is forced to work helplessly according to their qualities. Even no one can maintain their physical body without work.

> Bg 3.3 — The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: O sinless Arjuna, I have already explained that there are two classes of men who try to realize the self. Some are inclined to understand it by empirical, philosophical speculation, and others by devotional service.
>
> Bg 3.4 — Not by merely abstaining from work can one achieve freedom from reaction, nor by renunciation alone can one attain perfection.
>
> Bg 3.5 — Everyone is forced to act helplessly according to the qualities he has acquired from the modes of material nature; therefore no one can refrain from doing something, not even for a moment.
>
> Bg 3.6 — One who restrains the senses of action but whose mind dwells on sense objects certainly deludes himself and is called a pretender.
>
> Bg 3.7 — On the other hand, if a sincere person tries to control the active senses by the mind and begins karma-yoga [in Kṛṣṇa consciousness] without attachment, he is by far superior.
>
> Bg 3.8 — Perform your prescribed duty, for doing so is better than not working. One cannot even maintain one’s physical body without work.
>
> Bg 3.9 — Work done as a sacriﬁce for Viṣṇu has to be performed; otherwise work causes bondage in this material world. Therefore, O son of Kuntī, perform your prescribed duties for His satisfaction, and in that way you will always remain free from bondage.